# How to get personalized sub-domains for users and make them work?

Tags: url-rewriting, subdomain

Say I have a site hosted on *example.com*, now I want each of my registered user to get a personalized sub-domain, e.g Alice should normally gets *alice.example.com* as her sub-domain. While actually *alice.example.com* gets data from *example.com/user/alice*. How to implement this mechanism? I see lots of sites are working in this way. I wonder how they did it. Is it some kind of domain server configuration, web-server configuration, .htaccess rewrite or simply some tricks in the code?

If its redirecting, as I experimented, *example.com* and *alice.example.com* will get DIFFERENT IP addresses, if that, how rewrite works since when I request *alice.example.com*, the web browser takes me to a completely different site (IP address).

This has confused me for some time, I just can't figure it out myself, any help would be really appreciated.

[edit]: OK WAIT! I'm afraid I made a duplicate. Check this thread: [Create subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)

Comment: Can't help you. But i gotta say it. Its a good Question.

Comment: A word of advice, try asking this question at serverfault.com the Server guys are usually there.

Comment: To me. Server fault right now is still kinda a small village. The other reason I put this question here was I wasn't sure if it's programming related or system admin stuff. Sorry to found that someone already asked this. See 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need two parts:

1) Your Nameserver needs to support wildcards. So you would map *.mydomain.com to a single server. This will cause alice.mydomain.com and bob.mydomain.com to all go to the same server.

2) Then your server software should be able to map the hostname (=alice.mydomain.com) to your application and pass in the "alice" part as a parameter.

Depending in what framework/server software you use this should be quite easy.

HTH
Alex

Comment: Thanks. I'm on goDaddy, wondering if their nameserver supports wildcards.

Comment: @Shawn: their nameserver supports nothing that may aid you.  Consider using nameserver of your hosting provider.

Comment: goDaddy support suggested me to add a wildcard A record to point to my main domain's ip. Will that work?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it some kind of domain server configuration, web-server configuration, .htaccess rewrite or simply some tricks in the code?

It's probably a combination of the several techniques.

First layer would probably be a [Wildcard DNS record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) on a DNS level so that any sub-domain can be used.

Next, server configuration or application logic is used to separate the content based on the accessed sub-domain. This can be Apache Alias directive or a Rewrite rule or logic in your application code.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell how I did this on pastebin.com

- wildcard DNS makes *.pastebin.com go to a single IP
- By default, if Apache can't find a matching vhost for a given domain, the first defined vhost picks it up (there are other ways of achieving this, this is just what I did).
- So I ensure the pastebin site is the first vhost, and so then software then sees the requested hostname and acts on it accordingly to configure itself

Comment: Thanks. How did deal with www. and other none www. subs? I suppose ass *.mydomain.com suggests, www.mydomain.com should be excluded when doing the wildcard thing?