# Rewrite sub-domain to directory

Tags: url-rewriting

I'd like to map `subdomain.example.com` to `www.example.com/subdomain` using an internal URL rewrite that looks at the host name and simply forwards any request to a subdirectory with the same name as the subdomain.

Thanks for your help

Comment: This needs to be done on the server level. What web server do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourdomain\.com 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And how does this answer the question?

Comment: Assuming you use Apache, you can use this .htaccess file to do the redirects for you. Ow, have I misread the mapping part ?

Comment: Sorry yes it's Apache.  This answer pointed me in the right direction, thank you.

Comment: This answer redirects the user's browser to the said page. The question was about internally rewriting the request to a subdirectory that is intended to host the subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

See the following for [subdomain part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php/586160#586160) if you are on Apache:

> 1. You need to create a wildcard domain on your DNS server *.website.com
> 2. Then in your vhost container you will need to specify the wildcard aswell *.website.com - This is done in the ServerAlias http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#serveralias

Then you will want to use a rewrite rule similar to the one posted by pritaeas or get the domain with you PHP script and redirect based upon it.

```
$url = substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '.'));
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/$url");
```

Comment: These instructions are for redirections, not rewrites. Just like the accepted answer.