# How to map SubDomain to the subfolder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, blogengine.net

Hi I'm using a BlogEngine.net for my blog and I would like to create 5 different subdomains and point to different subfolders(**not redirecting**). For example:

```
firstsubdomain.domain.com - domain.com/posts/helloworld.aspx
firstsubdomain2.domain.com - domain.com/posts/helloworld2.aspx
firstsubdomain3.domain.com - domain.com/posts/helloworld3.aspx
```

Thank you in advance for working example. 
I'm using asp.net 3.5, C#, Windows Server 2008, IIS 7

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a new web site in IIS manager, point it to the folder where the files are, and set the hostname to subdomain.domain.com

Comment: That will work, but I need the solution which not required creating additional websites, maybe just one to handle all mapping. Because right now I need to create 5 subdomains and tomorrow it can be 200 so in my case creating a separate website for each subdomain not a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [URL rewriting](http://forums.asp.net/p/1525835/3680454.aspx) if you limitation on IIS and if you have full control on IIS then can do using .[htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413253):

Check these links for more details:

[Web.config and mapping subdomains to folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660717/web-config-and-mapping-subdomains-to-folders)

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/465/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference/

https://help.brinkster.com/KB/a125/how-do-i-redirect-a-domain-or-subdomain.aspx#b3

check this [Ionic's ISAPI Rewrite Filter](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/IIRF.aspx)

IIRF is an ISAPI filter that does URL Rewriting for IIS. It's small, FREE, and easy to use. It is easy to install, fast, and powerful. You can get Search-Engine Friendly (SEF) or Search-Engine Optimized (SEO) URLs easily on IIS 6, 7, or 7+. It works with what you have, and there's help available to get you going. You can get the source code to inspect it or even modify it yourself.