# How do I map a subdomain to a subdirectory?

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain, subdirectory

I would like to display the contents of a subdirectory when someone hits a specific subdomain. `http://my.example.us/` should show the content of `http://example.us/sync`.

EDIT: This is what I have so far. It doesn't appear to effect my URL at all.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(my)\.example\.us$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.us/sync/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What server software are you using? cPanel etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Rewrite sub-domain to directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413253/rewrite-sub-domain-to-directory)

Comment: I'm using dreamhost. They don't use cpanel. They wrote their own from what I understand. I asked their support about this issue and they said they don't have anything that will do what I'm trying.

Comment: @Havelock I promise I searched first! LOL. It does look like mine is a dupe. I'll check that one out. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Just replace 'mirror' with 'map' or something similar and search again :)

Comment: mod_rewrite will help redirect from one to another but you still need to create the sub domain.

Comment: I've created the subdomain. I've tried a number of solutions I've found here on stackoverflow and other blogs but none of them are working for me. Do I put the `.htaccess` file in the root of the "main" URL directory or do I put it in the root of the new subdirectory?