# user-based subdomains

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)

for one of my scripts, i want it so that each of my clients has their own subdomain

however, i want each subdomain to use the exact same script, and the exact same database

can this be accomplished with HTACCESS?

example: john.mysite.com would take them to my script, setting a username variable as john...so they can be identified in the database...

how can i do this?

Comment: Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `ServerAlias` directive in your VirtualHost configuration to `*.mysite.com`.  You can then use `mod_rewrite` in the `.htaccess` to append the username to the URL, or use PHP to pull the subdomain off the requested URL, and do whatever you want with it.