# Tumblr-style multiple domains

Tags: php, authentication, dns

I'm building a web app that's a little similar to Tumblr in that we'd run everything through one domain, but we'd actually have sites with other domain names running off the same app.

That is:

```
    Platform (platform.dev)
    |
    |_app1 (app1.dev)
    |_app2 (app2.dev)
```

They'd share the same web server, database server, auth server.

To keep things simple, how would I set up custom domains? On top of that, how would I handle authentication?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both your DNS & web Servers to host wildcard domains. Can't tell you more without details of your setup, but see here for a [BIND + Apache example](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/358) on Debian.

Also, what part of authentication are you concerned about? Need more details there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about wildcard domains - how about domains that are unrelated to the base domain entirely? Would that be covered under the wildcard domain change?

Comment: No, you'll have to configure those too, but you can configure apache to serve content from the same directory for those domains too (so that one instance of your app can serve them all).

Comment: Hey Skjaidev, thanks for the reply.

So from what I understand, the process for custom domain names is adding an A record to the domain itself (cf. Tumblr's process), then I'd have to set up a virtual host on my HTTP server to serve the content?

Is it possible to automate virtual host setup?