# Want to create dynamic subdomain in codeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

In my site i want to add an functionality for user to use their username with domain.

Like in codeigniter right now i want to give the user to use their own url to login in site and do other stuff.

For eg:

i Want `www.username.mysite.com/login` or `www.username.mysite.com/category`

so here the user can login with their credential and add the category. so i have two controller in my site with login and category.

So how to do this with the routes Or .htaccess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)

Answer (score 3):

Use this code in server Vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/yourdoma/public_html/yourdomain"
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/yourdomain.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/yourdomain.local-access.log" common
    <Directory "/home/yourdoma/public_html/yourdomain">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/yourdoma/public_html/yourdomain"
    ServerName dummy-host.yourdomain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/yourdomain.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/yourdomain.com-access.log" common
    ServerAlias *.yourdomain.com
    <Directory "/home/yourdoma/public_html/yourdomain">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and For your codeigniter config file:

```
$host = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : '';
$schema = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://' : 'http://';
$spl_host = explode("mysite.com", $host);
$subhost = '';
if (count($spl_host) == 2) {
    $subhost = current($spl_host);
}

if($host == $subhost.'mysite.com') {
    $config['base_url'] = $schema.$subhost.'mysite.com';
} else {
    $config['base_url'] = $schema.$host;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here's an explanation of your issue here. http://www.joehayes.org/setting-up-wildcard-dns-for-subdomains.html

Ok if you have read the explanation on the link, you'd know that you should redirect all of your subdomains to www first. in httpd.conf file there's a virtual host definition containing only **yourdomain.com** to redirect all the requests to your DocumentRoot.

```
**ServerAlias yourdomain.com**
ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot /home/yourdoma/public_html
BytesLog domlogs/yourdomain.com-bytes_log
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
User yourdomain
Group yourdomain
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/yourdomain.com combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/yourdomain/public_html/cgi-bin/
```

and you should modify the **ServerAlias** to ***.yourdomain.com** to retrieve all subdomains into your **Document Root** folder. then you should be able to **mod_rewrite** or **url parse** your uri to succeed this.

Comment: Sorry, not a proper answer, what i need.

Comment: ok, i just wanted to point that whether you have a ssh access to your host, or access to httpd.conf file, or restarting the apache server.

Comment: No i dont have any access. but what is the connection of creating dynamic subdomain with server??

Comment: if you do not have access to the server to amend the dns/webserver details as suggested, the i doubt you will be able to achieve what you want.