# How to create dynamic subdomains in codeigniter with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, dynamic, subdomain

am using codeigniter, I want to set up .htaccess to make dynamic subdomains. And I cannot figure out how. 
I am trying to create custom domain names using .htaccess

Currently my URL looks like this:

> http://www.example.com/public/stores/shop/products

I need it to look like this:

> http://www.shop.example.com/public/stores/products

but it throws a 404?

stores - controller name, 
shop   - dynamic name

The problem is that each shop should get a sub-domain automatically.Would be great if you could share the work around for the code & the .htaccess

I tried this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-_]+).example.com [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/controller/function/%2 [P]

   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736737/want-to-create-dynamic-subdomain-in-codeigniter

Comment: Just create a new sub-directory copy the application folder paste it into new directory as well as index.php and on the index.php file make sure you change location of `../system` and if you would like to create library in systems lib folder and use get instance. Creating library's are easier if you have multi sub directories.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I would like to let you know that the sub-directories(store name) has to create dynamically.Please let me know your thoughts.