# how to create subdomain dynamically with .htaccess in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i had some problem for creating dynamic sub domain.

this is my url now:

> domain.com/username

how it become:

> username.domain.com

this is my .httacess

```
RewriteEngine On<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*<br>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]<br>
\RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br>
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]<br>
Options +Indexes<br>
```

have a idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736737/want-to-create-dynamic-subdomain-in-codeigniter

Comment: that not what i want. i need with .htacces

Answer (score 0):

Hi try bellow code its working fine for me

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```