# How can I redirect a website from domain.com/blog to blog.domain.com?

Tags: .htaccess, web

I have a website with a wordpress blog. This blog can be accessed from domain.com/blog.

Now I want to make a redirect (via htacces) from domain.com/blog to blog.domain.com;

how can I do it?

In internet I found the opposite problem :\

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840400/using-subdirectory-as-subdomain-in-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

go into your cpanel (the webserver) just find "redirect domain" there .
open that and add the desired domain against  to your current domain address..
and thats all

Comment: don't you have any solutions via .htacces?