# How to handle dynamic sub-domains in React and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, subdomain

I'm building a blogging website where I want the name of the user to be added as a sub-domain dynamically. An example of what I require is shown below.

[image]

Since the user decides the blog name, I am neither sure whether I'm supposed to handle this on React or Node, nor how to handle it.

Comment: This has a slightly larger scope because it involves DNS resolution as well. That is, you need to make sure any *.blogg.se subdomains all resolve to the same host. See this thread for a how-to and a discussion of drawbacks: https://serverfault.com/questions/12124/wildcard-dns-and-subdomains
And for your React app, you would use the approach discussed here to render dynamically based on the subdomain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201258/how-to-get-a-subdomain-using-window-location

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create dynamic subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834403/create-dynamic-subdomains)