# How to create dynamic subdomains with .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)

I'd like to have the following domains structure with .htaccess:

```
domain.com        REWRITES TO   Home Page (index.php)

www.domain.com    REWRITES TO   Home Page (index.php)

blog.domain.com   REWRITES TO   index.php?page=blog

*.domain.com      REWRITES TO   index.php?page=user&id=* (where * can be anything)
```

Is there a way to create anything like this?

Comment: Check out [this link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php) It's another question like yours with a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated which hostname you want your rewrites to use so I am assuming the www subdomain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}domain.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/index.php [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=blog [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)[.]domain.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=user&id=%1 [R,L]
```