# How to create subdomain for URL Alias in Drupal php

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have created a multilingual site in Drupal. So I have `www.mydomain.com/jp` for Japanese language and I want to create a subdomain like `www.jp.mydomain.com` for `www.mydomain.com/jp`.

The problem is that Drupal does not create a folder for each language. For subdomains I updated my `.htaceess` file with a rewrite rule.

Please suggest what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using drupal, then you can use [subdomain](http://drupal.org/project/subdomain) module. And if want to do the same with .htaccess(php), then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php) link.

I think it will help you.