# How to call example.domain.com instead of www.domain.com/example

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've seen many website doing this, for example in the address bar : we can type: someuser.twitter.com and it will automatically redirect us to twitter.com/someuser

I know this can be done using HTACCESS. Could some one help me please on what to write on the htaccess file in order to call example.domain.com instead of domain.com/example ?

Thank-you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look at this well explained topic:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php
```