# Dynamic Subdomain map to a folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting

I want to create dynamic subdomain for each user and redirect to a folder.
for example someone access with myname.example.com it should be redirect to example.com/survey.php

I am sending a newsletter to more than 500 people and each user will get a link of subdomain with name.
like 
john.example
jess.example.com

I can't create 500 sub-domains.So please help me about each step that should be taken to achieve this goal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have other subdomains in place?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php) is a link that might be useful. What if users are 10000, for example, subdomains for all? [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain) is also a link with a definition  of **subdomain**.