# creating subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am not familiar with .htaccess .  I am trying to create .htaccess file which will redirect the any subdomain to portfolio.

For example : `bob.example.com` ,

which will redirect to the bob portfolio. in background script will be executed following way.

```
example.com/portfolio.php?id=bob
```

I have written following .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)[.]example.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com/portfolio/index.php?id=%1 [R,L]
```

Issue is , if i use bob.example.com then it actually redirect to `example.com/portfolio/index.php?id=bob`

if use bob.example.com then must open portfolio direct , instead of redirection

Alright , i managed my self to create it

```
RewriteRule ^$ portfolio/index.php?id=%1 [NC,L]
```

Above statement works perfectly ! Thank you !

Comment: check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php?rq=1

Comment: They thank you but not so useful

Comment: Don't use `.htaccess` for this. Set up a proper vhost configuration and store it in sites-available. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/index.html

Comment: I am using aws , I have added A record in domain control panel. Now i just trying to create virtual domains using .htaccess.

Comment: Have you got access to ssh and possibility to create symulinks?

Comment: yeah i have SSH .. Why there is need of symlink ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/portfolio/index.php?id=%1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Although I wouldn't recommend you to do this. If you're working with some kind of MVC framework then I'm sure it's routing components can accomplish this for you.