# Adding text before the site url

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

Example:

You know the site about.com ?
They have a whole subset of url's such as: pottery.about.com

---

My question: How to get the "pottery" in front of the URL?

Anybody have some nifty mod_rewrite to do this?

Thanks!

David

Comment: This may help you, if you do not want to setup all the subdomains manually as recommended below by @Cam : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are considered sub domains, you can set them up most of the time through any hosting company. Usually they dont charge you for them, but some do. They are very easy to setup and can be done quickly versus regular domain names.