# How to create a subdomain using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to create a subdomain mobile.example.com that this subdomain to open through directory "mobile" example.com/mobile.

I try to use so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mobile\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/$1 [L]
```

Comment: check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

Comment: Look at this post, here's an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/586160/8791676

Answer (score 2):

Creating a subdomain using htaccess is impossible. it's a DNS issue. You'll have to configure DNS in a way that client requests for this sub domain will be send to *your* web server.

Comment: hek2mgl can u give me your skype id?

Comment: Sounds like a request for a larger support session. You'll have to pay for that. But whats wrong with communication here? maybe I can help using the comments here as well - unpaid. This would make the communication open for all.

Comment: ok so i dont know how to configure DNS that client request for subdomain to sent to my webserver.. please help me?

Comment: Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: than DNS configuration will be made by them. If creating sud domains is part of your contract then most hosters provide a web gui where you can create sub domains.

Comment: Problem is here because i use codeigniter framework and i want to make my controller subdomain.. for example: http://example.com/controller => controller.example.com

Comment: The process is fully transparent for the PHP level. You only need to deploy a regular website to the webspace of the sub.domain. However, for me it looks weeeeeirrrd what you are about to do

Comment: if you can't understand it's maybe a little bit too much for you at the moment. why do you need that?