# PHP user registration with subdomain creation

Tags: php, authentication, subdomain

I am looking for a solution for develop user registration system with creating sub domain for each user, e.g.

My domain is

> www.example.com

When a user creates an account he could be able to access that created account at

> www.user_name.example.com

I am trying to do this in PHP.

What is the best approach to do this kind of login system?

If you know any tutorial(s) it will be great help for me.

Comment: Not sure of my answer so I post as comment, but I would do it with virtualhosts and ServerPath with a rewrite rule to pass parameter to PHP http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html#serverpath

Answer (score 2):

In your DNS server:

```
*.example.com.   3600  A  127.0.0.1
```

In your Apache VirtualHost configuration:

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

In your code:

```
$match = preg_match(
    '/^www\.(.+)\.example.com$/', 
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 
    $matches
);

if ($match) {
    $user_name = $matches[1];
    //stuff when dynamic subdomain detected
}
```

For more details you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586160/2905135).

Comment: I am thinking to go with URL re writing with .htaccess file. is that good approach.?