# Create a Subdomain in godaddy hosting using PHP

Tags: php, dns, hosting, subdomain, web-hosting

Is there any easiest way to create a sub domain using PHP code on godaddy.com hosting?

e.g:

```
jon.mywebsite.com
jessie.mywebsite.com
```

etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

Comment: Hmmm... Why not create it via their CP? I think it will be easier. :)

Comment: I don't want to create 10,000 subdomains one by one,, (TOO MUCH time Consuming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a A record to serve all your subdomains

```
*.your-site.com       IN  A       YOUR-IP-ADDRESS
```

then you need to create a .htaccess file and

```
RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|gif|jpg)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?uri=$1&hostName=%{HTTP_HOST}
```

this will ignore images (SEO friendly URLs).

> Now you can redirect your users to $userName.your-site.com

Alternatively try this:

setup your application so your users goes to
your-site.com/user
your .htaccess should look like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$  index.php?username=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.mywebsite.com
RewriteRule (.*)  index.php?username=%1
```

so now when you hit the index.php it will grab the user and redirect to $user.your-site.com as a custom subdomain. (in this case usernames are limited to a-z characters)

Comment: I've setuped the A record
but, .htaccess is not pointing me to the required page

Comment: I've edited the answer, take a look at the alternative method, hope that helps

Comment: Still same... nothing happen..
I can just see there "pageok"

Comment: @muaaz,when exactly are you are getting "pageok"? and what does that mean?
I'm assuming this is a godaddy generic page and you followed the steps  I mentioned above and everything works as desired.

Comment: it means, sub-domain is not being pointed to any location in my hosting.. 
I just came to know that, I need to buy WildCard certificate to achieve the goal.

Comment: oooh #GodaddyCommercialism, @muaaz I suggest you look at dedicated cloud services like VPS(Virtual private services)/AWS amazon etc... you will need a bit of linux familiarity (which you can reference to on youtube/books)to get started but it will save you lots of money in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think with PHP Code you can but with the help of .htaccess i think it is possible.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+jon/
RewriteRule ^jon/(.*)$ http://jon.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+jessie/
RewriteRule ^jessie/(.*)$ http://jessie.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(jon|jessie)/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?jon\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /jon/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?jessie\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /jessie/$1 [L]
```

You can make subdomain much easier using control panel, why to do it the hard way ?

Comment: well, that's also acceptable. BUT, I need it to be general
like 
if I have url like this
http://www.username.mywebsite.com

using htaccess it should point me to
http://www.mywebsite.com/username

username can be vary

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in case anyone is looking for the answer. This is specific to GoDaddy, but other Hosts may do something similar to this.

After you setup your DNS A record you need to go to Hosted Domains and add the subdomain folder name under the root domain account.
Go to Hosted Domains.
Under Hosted Domains you will see a root domain table column.
You will also see a Subdomains table column with an "Add" link.
This link is for adding subdomains to a root domain.
Type in/enter the name of the subdomain folder.

Create either an index.php or index.html file and upload it to your subdomain folder and echo something like "Setup Completed". I noticed that if you are doing something like creating a restricted "api" subdomain for example and the GD script cannot access the index file in your subdomain folder then the "process" does not complete until you add a plain index.php or index.html file in your subdomain folder. After that is done then you can add anything you want in that subdomain folder/site.