# Htaccess - redirect - 2 similar links

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have 2 similar links: 
1. subdomain.portal.pl/page/
2. portal.pl/page/

When i try to visit the first link it always redirect me to second link. 
How can i tell the difference in `.htaccess` for those two links?

Comment: as it is already redirected, htaccess can not see the difference. You should try to find where it redirects and change that.

Comment: [look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)... may be you can find your issue or missing part..