# How to redirect non WWW to WWW with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I know this is a duplicate question but I tried all the answers here on stackoverflow and many results on google but nothing works.I even tried to use this htaccess redirect generator http://www.htaccessredirect.com/ that gave me this code

```
## Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a.solutionbanks.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:## www.a.solutionbanks.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

that also didn't work.
all what I am trying to do is to redirect from a.solutionbanks.com to --> www.a.solutionbanks.com

Comment: As far as I know it's easier to do this using a `ServerAlias` (if you are using Apache atleast..) look here: [Serveralias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong at many places. Try this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.solutionbanks\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

#### [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: not working.. when I open a.solutionbanks.com it redirects me to http://www.a.solutionbanks.com/a/

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: yes i am sure my .htaccess is enabled. i have used it before and this time its working but the result is not correct becaause the code is wrong

Comment: What code is wrong? Did you do verification as I told and got 500 as a result? If you have other rules then make sure this rule is places as very first rule.

Comment: yes i did the verification the .htaccess is enabeled
no i dont have other rules currently

Comment: It is not working because you are using `nginx/1.6.2` which is not Apache.

Comment: [This should help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967574/shell-script-grep-command-for-wild-cards)

Comment: but how is the .htaccess working without apache?
it was working before
and actually its working now when i open
a.solutionbanks.com/tools/sendmail.php it redirects to www.a.solutionbanks.com/tools/sendmail.php
its only the homepage thats not working

Comment: a.solutionbanks.com/index.php redirect correctly 
but a.solutionbanks.com redirects to www.a.solutionbanks.com/a
thats the only wrong one

Comment: I just tested and `http://a.solutionbanks.com` got redirected to `http://www.a.solutionbanks.com/` and there was no `/a/` in the end. Make sure to test in a new browser to avoid old cache.