# Shell Script: Grep command for wild cards

Tags: shell

Can anyone please tell me how to grep below line because when i try to grep it, it is giving wrong results.

```
*/5 * * * * /home/file.sh"
```

Comment: What do you want to `grep`? What did you try?

Comment: Define "wrong results" as well as "expected results".

Comment: In crontab if '*/5 * * * * /home/file.sh' is present then again i need not to add this entry. But when i try to grep this one and compare it, it is showing entry not present and once again it is getting added there. If i run my script for 10 times then 10 times this is getting added in crontab

Comment: easier as 100 words, is showing your script what do you tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep -F` (fixed strings):

```
grep -F '*/5 * * * * /home/file.sh' cron.txt
*/5 * * * * /home/file.sh
```