# How to make dynamic subdomain in shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I wanted to make dynamic subdomain in my shared hosting but I don't have access to httpd.conf file and any of the server file. I have already created a wildcard subdomain in my cpanel.

I just wanted to make this url: **www.example.com/books.php?tag=Love-Books&current_page=2** (after .httaccess manipulation the url is **www.example.com/Love-books/2**) to work like subdomain like **www.Love-Books.example.com** and all the other url to work normally. I have this code on my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)$ authors.php?current_page=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ books.php?tag=$1&current_page=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^Books-single/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ book-single.php?tag=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^Books-by/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ book-by.php?auth=$1&current_page=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^authors-by/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ authors-by.php?author-by=$1&current_page=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

This guide can help you understand the process: [Create Subdomains on the Fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php") using the `.htaccess` file and with `PHP`.

Comment: as i said i don't have access to any server files how will i perform step 2 of your link... Include the wildcard in vhost