# How do I add a subdomain to cloudflare in PHP "on the fly"?

Tags: php, dns, cloudflare

how would I add a subdomain to my cloudflare account for a specific domain on the fly? Is this possible to do, how do other websites tend to create subdomains in code?

Comment: do they have an api for dns settings?

Comment: Ehh, not too familiar with using API's. But it appears so [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/docs/client-api.html).

Comment: I don't know much about configuring Cloudflare, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php) details creating subdomains with PHP.

Comment: https://www.cloudflare.com/docs/client-api.html#s5.1 looks like what you ant

Comment: I'll have a read and see what I can do, cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudflare has an API, https://www.cloudflare.com/docs/client-api.html#s5.1.

There is also a PHP library for Cloudflare as well. https://github.com/vexxhost/CloudFlare-API

Comment: Looking at the PHP library, they appear to have a way of adding records, etc. Why the downvote?

Comment: The community probably wants to see code because alas links can go 404. It's a good resource, though.