# How do i create virtual subdomain using htaccess?

Tags: subdomain

I would like to create virtual sub domains for clients who will have websites with us but the websites will be served from a single url in reality for example;

---

***main site:***

domain.com/post/20/Posttitle

domain.com/index.php?r=post/20/Posttitle

***sub site:***

mysub.domain.com

domain.com/index.php?s=mysub

OR

mysub.domain.com/post/20/Posttitle

domain.com/index.php?s=mysub&r=post/20/Posttitle

OR

mysub.domain.com/Cat/2/cattitle

domain.com/index.php?s=mysub&r=Cat/2/cattitle

OR

mysub.domain.com/{OrderURL}

domain.com/index.php?s=mysub&r={OrderURL}

....

** In a general example: **Blog system**

---

How do i do this?

Also my setup is with PHP{Something like the MVC} and cPanel / WHM server.

Note: The design on localhost

Here is the htaccess code i have tried so far (does not work properly);

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(http://|https://)?(www\.)?(.*\.)?(.*)$
RewriteRule (http://|https://)?(www\.)?(.*\.)?(.*)$ index.php?s=$3&r=$4 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?r=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: what is the actual question? How to create a subdomain or how to use RewriteRule?

Comment: Use RewriteRule  To create a virtual subdomain. for example site: sub.blogsky.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)

Comment: Thanks, but the site structure does not allow the use of this solution.