# create subdomain with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been searching the forums and web with no working solutions. I tried almost every solutions found here but so far no luck....
Here is it: I have a website 
`http://example.com/user=me`
and I want that when the user enter 
`me.example.com` he gets the content of 
`http://example.com/user=me` . note that I do not have a me.example.com subdomain, how can I achieve this?
Maybe relevent if I add that I'm on a shared server.
I've seen many .htaccess script, copied and pasted them but so far no luck.

here is my htaccess (for removing the .php)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55  .php55 .php
```

any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

Comment: thanks but I visited this question and it did not do the trick

Comment: did you follow every step? its not just a.htacess file you need to edit

Comment: well, one was wildcart on private server and for the other, they said just modify .htaccess ... Could you explain the whole process for .htaccess?

Comment: the whole process could not be any clear than what is set out on that post. if you feel this is is not a duplicated post again with details of what you have done and where exactly you are stuck