# How to Redirect Mobile Users to Your Mobile Site with Redirectron?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mobile

I have set up a website which is a full 960 grid website then within the full website I have a directory for mobile which I would like to redirect users to if they visit the website by mobile devices.

I have set a domain alias for my domain m.somewebsite.co.uk and my .htaccess file look like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.eygcommercial\.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/
RewriteRule (.*) /mobile/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(m\.|)eygcommercial\.co.uk 
RewriteRule (.*) http://eygcommercial.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in my connection file I have added the following code:

```
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
header('Location: http://m.eygcommercial.co.uk/');
```

The issue I am having is when I access the website via my iPhone I get an error "Safari cannot open the page because too many redirect occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only javascript:

```
<script language="javascript"><!--
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
 if (mobile) {
 window.location.href='http://m.eygcommercial.co.uk';
 } //-->
</script>
```

Update: Support for mobile redirection using the same url path

```
<script language="javascript"><!--
var subdomain = 'http://m.';
var url = window.location.href;
var rest = url.match(/:\/\/\w+\.(.+)/)[1];
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
 if (mobile) {
 window.location.href= subdomain + rest;
 } //-->
</script>
```

Also you need to modify htaccess and template script in order to allow the subdomain and serve the mobile template: [Create subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)

Comment: Excellent many thanks for you answer and advice. Works perfectly.

Comment: Nice to know this helped you out!

Comment: I wondered if you could help with the following, what I am trying to do now is set this up so if we go to www.somewebsite.co.uk/products/test it redirect to the m.somewebsite.co.uk/products/test, it does work but the URL becomes www.somewebsite.co.uk/mobile/products/test/test?

Comment: I've edited my post. now the javascript will redirect to mobile subdomain using the same url path.

Answer (score 1):

You Can you following code in JavaScript like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
   if (screen.width <= 800) {
       window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
   }
   //-->
</script>
```

or in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check for mime types commonly accepted by mobile devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ http://m.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```