# Subdomain points to subdirectory dynamically through htaccess without changing URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want dynamically points sub domain to sub directory through htaccess without changing the urls and directory listing shows below.

```
|-- Test (Root Directory) <-- test.com redirects to this folder.
|-- index.php
|
|-- subdomain (Directory)
|
|---- abc (Directory) <-- abc.test.com redirects to this folder.
|------ index.php
|
|---- pqr (Directory) <-- pqr.test.com redirects to this folder.
|------ index.php
|
|---- xyz (Directory) <-- xyz.test.com redirects to this folder.
|------ index.php
```

I have applied following rewrite rule to points subdomain.

## .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://test.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com $
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.test.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/$1
```

I am not that much good in htaccess rewrite.

I have follow this [subdomain on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)

But I couldn't succeeded. Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://test.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.com/subdomain/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I want to do this with without changing any url. For e.g. test.com points to root directory and abc.test.com points to abc(sub-folder) but without changing url.

Comment: Is your domain is a wildcard domain? If not you need to setup that on your DNS server

Comment: I have setup *.test.com on my DNS server.