# Allowing links to work from a root domain path and a subdomain path

Tags: php, hyperlink, nav

Thanks in advance for the help.

My problem is, I'm wanting to get my navigation working the file setup through the hosting is:

```
/home/webhosting/public_html/dev/
/* dev is my development folder also setup as a sub domain */
```

I want to access the links to allow www.mydomain.com/dev/login to link the login page in the dev section and same if i go 
dev.mydomain.com/login it will take me to the same login page for the dev domain (www.mydomain.com/dev/login) without giving me errors or taking me back to the root domain (www.mydomain.com/login)

so far i'm just using

```
DEFINE('ROOT', '/home/ganderz1/public_html/hosting/shadowtech.co.nz/dev/dev4/');

/* Define the Template to be used */
DEFINE('TEMPLATE_NAME', "default");

//DEFINE('ROOT', '');
DEFINE('TEMPLATE', ROOT.'Include/Theme/'.TEMPLATE_NAME.'/Language/en/Template/Common/');
DEFINE('HOME', ROOT);

DEFINE('NAV', "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/");
```

Any help would be extremely grateful and received well

Comment: I guess that has nothing to do with php... you might have to set up your server that way... or use the .htaccess file. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

Comment: Thanks, I'm using paid hosting so I guess it's their system unless i can overwrite it