# Create dynamic subdomain for each category

Tags: .htaccess, magento, magento2

I want to create a dynamic subdomain for each category.

E.g. my side is www.bbq.com and when I select the xyz category it will redirect to **xyz.bbq.com** and when abc it will redirect to **abc.bbq.com** and so on.

I am using Magento 2 x, PHP 7, MySQL 6

For the above dynamic subdomain, I have created different store on one website. now i am redirecting properly to perticular category.

if suppose, i am redirecting to abc category i.e **abc.bbq.com** i want to show only those product who belonging to abc category i.e product is sort by category.

In what the way above things should be achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)

Answer (score 0):

Check my post for create the subdomains dynamically for your categories in [Create subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php) . Post title is `Wildcard subdomain creation methods`