# how to create subfolder to subdomain in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new in PHP I am trying to create a subfolder to subdomain.

For example:

```
http://demo.com/subfolder

           to 

http://subfolder.demo.com
```

any one help to create this function in php.

Comment: Please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)

Answer (score 0):

Create a subfolder in www folder and then create a sub domain using cpanel and set root path to created folder.
I don't think there is any role of function.php.

Comment: i don't want to create subdomain using cpanel. my question is i have subfolder but i want to show it lik sobdomain

Comment: what you mean by show? You want to have url like that?

Answer (score 0):

That's not done through PHP itself. You'd have to configure that on in your hosting panel where the application is hosted.

Try Googling for the hostingpanel you're using (*might be something like DirectAdmin or cPanel*). There are loads of guides on how to setup subdomains.

Also don't forget to change the DNS. Not all DNS-servers automatically tunnel through subdomains.

Best of luck!

Comment: You cannot configure that in PHP. That has to do with actually routing *to* your application. PHP cannot influence that area. If you want to link to the subdomain, something like `header('location: http://subfolder.demo.com/');` would work. But that does not seem to be your question.