# .htaccess - How to redirect file requests in a subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website that has custom subdomains for users, e.g. `creator.snaprate.me`.
This works great, but if I manually type in `creator.snaprate.me/login` the login page `(snaprate.me/login)` appears.

I'd like to have a redirect to `snaprate.me/anypage` for any subdomain, but don't know how.

I have the following .htaccess, and this has been working great except for this issue:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^((?!www\.)[^.]+).snaprate\.me$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+).snaprate\.me$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

What do I need to add in order to redirect traffic from `subdomain.snaprate.me/anypage` to `snaprate.me/anypage`? I'd really like an answer to this; I have been searching for days and still I have no idea what to do -- htaccess is my Achille's heel!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)

Comment: @nogad Not a duplicate, I edited to hopefully specify better.