# Dynamic subdomain handling in a .htaccess file for xxx.domain.com to redirect to a ../users folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, lamp

Here is where I am. I am great at CodeIgniter and general LAMP but not so great at .htaccess. I am setting up the PHP handling of dynamic subdomains in a user creation setting. Think mydomain.com can create and access user.mycomain.com and be served a page.

The design is this. in the document root of the Apache Server there is a "Users" folder that will house each user.

so /var/www/html being docroot, the Users folder is located at /var/www/html/Users/(user)

So Ideally I want a user to create their account, then my PHP controller runs then pow! Their (user).mydomain.com page is created.

I changed the nameserver so that *.mydomain.com resolved to my static IP. No issues there.

The issue lies in the .htaccess file. I have tried numerous suggestions here in StackOverflow but I am stuck on two things.

This is what I have tried so far
But I am stuck.

For clarification.--

If I go to my documentroot and create a folder xxx. Then create a index.php file that says "it works". I should be able to go to xxx.mydomain.com and get a simple page that says "it works"

The folder is : (docroot)/Users/xxx
The domain is: mydomain.com
The sub domain is : xxx.mydomain.com

So the what I am trying to do in a nushell is get an entry of: xxx.mydomain.com to serve a website located at (docroot)/Users/xxx

With most suggestions online it appends xxx.mydomain.com with /Users/xxx so that the url is xxx.mydomain.com/Users.xxx when it needs to just be xxx.mydomain.com

But the URL displayed in the browser should always remain xxx.mydomain.com not the xxx.mydomain.com/Users/subdomain (where it literally says subdomain regardless of what xxx is)

Currently I either get:

a URL of xxx.mydomain.com/Users/subdomain (where it literally says subdomain)
or a 500 server error

I have tried several different suggestions across different articles. Here is one such suggestion.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9/-]+)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^/Users/$1/

#Below Required for CodeIgniter

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

What I am trying to accomplish is not append a /Users/xxx to a URL. I want to redirect to a folder /Users/xxx based off of my (docroot)while maintaining xxx.mydomain.com as the URL.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: im not going to suggest this is a dupe, but it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

Comment: Great suggestion but none of it co-exists nicely with codeigniter

Comment: I'm not sure if htaccess can do this, but PHP might be your best bet as you can detect the domain (including subdomain) with the `$_SERVER` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since the capture occurs in the `RewriteCond` and not the `RewriteRule`, you should use `%1`, not `$1`. From the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> In addition to plain text, the Substitution string can include
>
> 1. back-references ($N) to the RewriteRule pattern
> 2. back-references (%N) to the last matched RewriteCond pattern
> 3. [...]

You also have two `RewriteCond` with no `RewriteRule`, which means that all four conditions must match for the last `Rule` to be applied.

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Users   # Stop the rewrite if the URL already contains /User
RewriteRule (.*) /Users/%1/$1 [L]
```

The stop condition is necessary because whenever a URI changes as a result of a rewrite, apache reevaluates all `RewriteRules` again. You can see how the processing works [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset).

Comment: When I try this as my .htaccess file I get a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9/-]+)\.mydomain\.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) /Users/%1/$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: The problem I see is when I call a subdomain it keeps trying to append a /Users/subdomain to the end of the URL, where is that coming from?And literally I mean "/Users/subdomain" even if i do test.mydomain.com

Comment: The only thing different from what what you put in your instructions is that it is a dev environment so \.mydomain\.com is actually \.dev\.mydomain\.com$

Comment: @socialbarf Right, because the `Rewrite` takes place again when the uri changes and matches again, let me update the answer... However, I've no clue about the `subdomain` part.

Comment: the logs says..   "[Mon Aug 12 19:31:31.853426 2019] [core:error] [pid 5546] [client 72.216.80.17:59828] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

Comment: @socialbarf I updated the answer. But is the url in the browserbar actually changing? That should only happen with a `[R]` flag.

Comment: The URL changes to xxx.mydomain.com/Users/subdomain (literally the word subdomain)

Comment: @socialbarf And there isn't another `.htaccess` file anywhere?

Comment: I just checked. There is not