# .htaccess https, www and subdomain silent rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I need to:

- add www, so user will:

  - type `https://example.com/test.html`
  - see in browser `https://www.example.com/test.html`
  - get file from `example.com/test.html`
- add http -> https redirect, so user will:

  - type `http://www.example.com/test.html`
  - see in browser `https://www.example.com/test.html`
  - get file from `example.com/test.html`
- add subdomain **silent** redirect, so user will:

  - type `https://new.example.com/test.html`
  - see in browser `https://new.example.com/test.html`
  - get file from `example.com/new/test.html`
- and of course combinated, for example:

  - type `http://new.example.com/test.html`
  - see in browser `https://new.example.com/test.html`
  - get file from `example.com/new/test.html`

Is this possible via .htaccess file, eventually how?

www and https forwarding is already working fine for me, but I do not know, how to do silent forwaring with subdomains:

```
RewriteEngine On

# https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^new\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please share your htaccess rule file in your question, which is encouraged as an efforts to put by questioners in their questions, thank you.

Comment: I have tried something, but I do not have anything in .htacces file now, because everything that I tried was not working.

Comment: Just as an effort try adding whatever you tried there is nothing right or wrong, else question may come in off topic category the, thank you. Once I add it, I will try to help here, cheers.

Comment: Thank you, I added rules for www and https, that is working fine for me, but I do not know how to add silent forwarding.

Comment: Are `new.example.com` and `example.com` pointing to same directory on same host?

Comment: Yes, they are. And I want to separate them.

Answer (score 1):

You may try these rules in site root .htaccess:

```sh
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# add www for main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# add https for all domains
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# for new domain silently forward to new/ directory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^new/ new%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

Make sure you don't have any other code except these lines in site root and you must clear browser cache completely.

Comment: Hello and thanks, I do not know, this is not working for me, too. I am still getting error 'too many redirects', but I think that the problem is at my hosting provider. I have solved it by PHP.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown attempts/samples, could you please try following. Please make sure to you your htaccess rules in following way and clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ new/index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ new/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I add this to .htacces file (so in .htaccess is only your code), browser says to me: The page isn’t redirecting properly, page redirected you too many times.

Comment: @TadeasekF, ok, there was a typo, I have fixed it, please have edited rules in your file and clear browser cache and try again then.

Comment: Thank you, but same error. I have even tried browser, that I have never used, but the error is same.

Comment: @TadeasekF, ok, I have edited the rules now, could you please try them now and let me know how it goes, thank you.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but still same error; ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: @TadeasekF, could you please do let me know what is the sample url you are hitting?

Comment: I tried for example https://example.com, https://www.example.com, http://new.example.com and nothing works.

Comment: @TadeasekF, ok, could you please do let me know non existing pages like `http://example.com` etc from which file you want to serve? eg--> index.php etc? Also where that file is present inside new folder? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: Yes, I want to serve for example: example.com/index.php and example.com/new/index.php as new.example.com

Comment: @TadeasekF, I have edited the rules now, could you please check my updated rules, please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: Thank you, still same. I always rerun incognito mode, is that all right?

Comment: @TadeasekF, ok, I have edited my rules now, yes please better to clear cache and then test your urls.

Comment: Same error again. I tried to clear everything from browser and then run incognito.

Comment: @TadeasekF, ok, where is your htaccess file present? It should be residing in same folder where you have new folder. Means folder `new` and htaccess should be placed in same folder, let me know on same.

Comment: Yes, I have /.htaccess, /index.php, /new/index.php

Comment: @TadeasekF, Then these rules should work. could you please place a test line(temporary purposes) `--------` along with my rules and check any rule if you get 500 internal error means its enabled else its not enabled, let me know how it goes, thank you.

Comment: Ok, I added ---- to each blank line in .htaccess and I got 500, so it looks enabled.

Comment: @TadeasekF, what url `example.com` gives you?

Comment: @TadeasekF, is it 404 or 500 or 403?

Comment: That is not shown - I am getting: This page isn’t working. Page redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: @TadeasekF, ok any other rules you have in your current htaccess apart from these? OR you want any other htaccess residing in any of the folders? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: A do not have anything other than your code in my htaccess file. I have only one htaccess file.

Comment: @TadeasekF, sure, you have created virtual host for sub domain?

Comment: No, I am testing it on my domain.

Comment: @TadeasekF, may be you could take a look to link https://stackoverflow.com/a/586160/5866580 for checking how to create sub domain in htaccess, though I am not that sure but give it a shot for reading and see how ti goes.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try to solve it. As I said, it is wonderfully that https and www is working fine, but when I try subdomain forwarding, it fails.

Comment: @TadeasekF, yeah once you have sub domain these rules should fly then, you could upvote my answer if this has helped you too, cheers.